# ClickOnce app crashed after obfuscation with Eazfuscator.NET 2023.2

Tags: wpf, clickonce, obfuscation, eazfuscator

I used Eazfuscator.NET 2023.2 to obfuscate my WPF app when publishing with ClickOnce but the app crashed whenever I opened it. I didn't see any error when publishing as well as when installing and opening the app. The installation time was also much shorter than the one I published without obfuscation.
So, my question is:

1. Do I really need to obfuscate the app since I don't see any dll file in the "Application Files" folder. The only files I see are AppName.dll.deploy, AppName.dll.manifest, AppName.exe.deploy.
2. Is there anyway to make the app works with Eazfuscator.NET?

Comment: While using Eazfuscator you need to be cautious for string literals used in code, also check if anywhere reflection is used. etc.

Comment: Apps should not get smaller when you obfuscate them so I'm suspicious about a shorter install time. Obfuscation is low value. You can still decompile if you put your mind to it. Personally, I would say if you need to protect your IP then your best approach is if your executable stays on your web server.

Comment: I beleive it's always a good idea to contact their support...

Comment: @ArtemRazin I sent them an email but they said I need to renew the support subscription.